# how to check if string in two different arrays match

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

I would like to check if a string `$value` in two different arrays match. If they match, do something. If they don't match, do something.

Here is the code to get the string value seperately but I would like if possible to combine them together and then compare the strings for a match.

Here is the first lookup

```
        $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence']);
        $exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString', 'ia5String');
        $oid = array('id-at-commonName');
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            foreach($exists as $field) {
                if(
                    array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
                    in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
                ) {
                    $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
                    echo $value;
                    break; // stop further looping
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the second lookup:

```
        $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['issuer']['rdnSequence']);
        $exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString', 'ia5String');
        $oid = array('id-at-commonName');
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            foreach($exists as $field) {
                if(
                    array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['issuer']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
                    in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['issuer']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
                ) {
                    $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['issuer']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
                    echo $value;
                    break; // stop further looping
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between the first and second lookup?

Comment: Hi Barmar, one is looking in `$cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']*` and the other is looking in `$cert['tbsCertificate']['issuer']*`

Comment: Instead of echoing the value, put it into a variable. Then compare the two variables. BTW, I suggest taking all that common code and putting it into a function. It can take `issuer` or `subject` as an argument. The function can return `$value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your lookup code in a function that takes the type as a parameter, and returns the value found. Then compare the two calls.

```
function lookup($cert, $type) {
    $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence']);
    $exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString', 'ia5String');
    $oid = array('id-at-commonName');
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach($exists as $field) {
            if(
                array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
                in_array($cert['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
            ) {
                $value = $cert['tbsCertificate'][$type]['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
                return $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

if (lookup($cert, 'subject') == lookup($cert, 'issuer')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: is that the complete code or should i be calling the function as well ? using it as is produces errors `Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 `

Comment: I missed one of the places where I needed to replace the hard-coded type with `$type`.

Comment: yep, that works!! if its not too much trouble, can i get your help including one more lookup criteria to this code? or should I open another thread?

Comment: Try doing it yourself. You'll never learn to program if you just keep getting people to do it for you. If you can't get it working, post a new question.

Comment: will do, the other lookup is in a different away but ill give it a crack first. thx for your help